# While loop affected by strcmp if statement. Why is this?

Tags: c

Basically, I am having issues with the while loop below in part of my program.

Here is the section of code I'm having issue with:

```
            char *nameOfTheCommand;
            char *arrayArgs[500];
            //track for redirection. If set, gives position of the file name. Else it equals zero
            int redirectionCheck=0;
            arrayArgs[0]=token;
            int i;
            i=0;
            //While still arguments to take in, do this
            while(arrayArgs[i]!=NULL)
            {
                i++;
                arrayArgs[i]=strtok(NULL, " \n");
                if(strcmp(arrayArgs[i], "<")==0)
                {
                     redirectionCheck=i;
                }
            }
```

All I want the code to do is loop through strtok and set it equal to arrayArgs[i]. If the strtok happens to pull out a "<" symbol, then I want redirection to be set to i.

This seems simple enough. Yet, if I include the if statement in the while loop, it seem that the while loop exits and no code after that executes. I put a printf statement after the while loop and it won't print anything, that is how I know that it is like the while loop just stops everything else running after it immidiately.

Yet, if I don't include the if statment, my code runs fine.

Can someone please explain to me why this if statment seems to be causing my while loop to not act correctly? As in, it seems the while loop just wont execute stuff after it if I include it. Thanks for any information.

Comment: Trace through it in a debugger? What happens when strtok fails and you pass a null pointer to strcmp?

Comment: Shouldn't `if(strcmp(arrayArgs[i], "<")==0) { redirectionCheck=i; }` be at the start of the `while` loop, before `i++`?

Comment: No, because arrayArgs[0] is set to token beforehand. I'm setting arrayArgs[1] and beyond, and purposely skipping arrayArgs[0];

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I have attempted gdb, but am having trouble following it honestly, especially with the child process.

Answer (score 1):

In the final iteration of the loop, you pass `NULL` to `strcmp`. This can be avoided by rearranging the loop:

```
i = 1;
// read subsequent tokens
while((arrayArgs[i] = strtok(NULL, " \n")) != NULL)
{
    if(strcmp(arrayArgs[i], "<") == 0)
    {
         redirectionCheck = i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

but I would also add a check on the value of `i`.